# Motion layout does not apply window insets

Tags: android, android-motionlayout, windowinsets

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(fab) { view, insets ->
        val lp = fab.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        lp.bottomMargin += insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
        fab.layoutParams = lp
        insets
    }
```

Motion layout does not pass any window insets to children in spite of consuming the insets explicit in the `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` listener.

The insets are applied correctly when `applyMotionScene` attribute of motion layout is set to `false`.

Comment: Are you facing the same issue in ConstraintLayout? or only in MotionLayout?

Comment: only in motion layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with(ml) { //ml -> your motionLayout id
                    updateState(R.id.start, ConstraintSet().apply {
                        clone(ml)
                        constrainHeight(viewWhichHeightNeedsToChange.id, height.dp + insets.systemWindowInsetTop)
                        applyTo(ml)
                    })
                    setState(R.id.end, ml.width, ml.height)
                    updateState(R.id.end, ConstraintSet().apply {
                        clone(ml)
                        constrainHeight(viewWhichHeightNeedsToChange.id, height.dp + insets.systemWindowInsetTop)
                        applyTo(ml)
                    })
                    setState(R.id.start, ml.width, ml.height)
                }
```

Basically you need to update padding/size of your views in both motion layout sets. Would be great if there is a way to do so without switching between states though. This code is executed in setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { }
works with

> androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3

Comment: Thanks @Denis.. I got it working after a day I asked the question. Came up with a similar solutions like yours.. I figured I had to explicitly update layout params in individual motion layout states. 
Could there be a better solution though. 

Comment: Are the `setState` calls neccessary?

Answer (score 3):

You can update each state directly, following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout#getConstraintSet(int)) `getConstraintSet` return link to state.

> Get the ConstraintSet associated with an id This returns a link to the
> constraintset But in most cases can be used. createConstraintSet makes
> a copy which is more expensive.

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(fab) { view, insets ->
    val bottom = lp.marginBottom + insets.systemWindowInsetBottom

    with(motionLaytout) {
        getConstraintSet(R.id.state_id).apply {
            setMargin(fab.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, bottom)
        }

        getConstraintSet(R.id.another_state_id).apply {
            setMargin(fab.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, bottom)
        }
    }

    insets
}
```